# How cross compile a file with an include statement is nominally impossible in NTFS?

Tags: windows, mapping, cross-compiling, preprocessor, ntfs

This is perhaps an overly constrained problem, but I am looking for creative solutions.

I need to compile a file on a Windows machine (i.e. NTFS) that has an include statement of the form:

```
#include "TST:\path\file.ext"
```

The obvious problem being that NTFS does not allow a drive to be mapped with greater than one letter (occasionally two on some systems).

The closest I have come to forcing this to work is using a Cygwin terminal to make a directory with the name "TST:" i.e.

```
mkdir TST:
```

The directory is created, and can be accessed through Cygwin, but it shows up in Windows Explorer as "TST" therefor the Windows based preprocessing does not recognize the include statement as having a valid path.

Any idea, other than changing the include statement, would be welcome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "TST:" is a device name, but not a DOS drive letter. In general, the native device namespace is accessible using the "\\?\" or "\\.\" prefix, e.g. "\\?\TST:\path\file.ext".

Comment: FYI, device names have nothing to do with the file system. Classic DOS paths are normalized into native device paths in the NT runtime library in ntdll.dll. That said, for what you tried here (i.e. `mkdir TST:`), NTFS does reserve colon in filenames. It's the delimitter in the full name specification (i.e. "filename:streamname:streamtype"), so Cygwin or anything else has to escape colons in a filename. It stored U+F038 in the name (note that colon is U+003a), which is in a private use block (U+E000 - U+F8FF).

Comment: “other than changing the include statement” Could you clarify why you cannot make this trivial change? This will help us in understanding the issue better.